# Google Apps script getFrom is undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

Trying to get all unread emails and save the pdf attachments to google drive. When looping through the threads I get an error saying getFrom is undefined. It used to work but doesn't anymore it gets to the first unread email and spits out the error.

```
var fileTypesToExtract = ['pdf'];
//Name of the label which will be applied after processing the mail message
var labelName = 'SaveToDrive';
function GmailToDrive(){
  //build query to search emails find if email doesnt have savetodrive label for duplicates
  var query = '';
  //GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('receipts-new')
  //filename:jpg OR filename:tif OR filename:gif OR fileName:png OR filename:bmp OR filename:svg'; //'after:'+getDateNDaysBack_(1)+
  for(var i in fileTypesToExtract){
    query += (query === '' ?('filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]) : (' OR filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]));
  }
  query = 'is:unread ' + query;
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  console.log(threads);
  var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
  var parentFolder;
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  if(threads == null){
    exit;
  }
  for(var i in threads){
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages;
    console.log(mesgs);
    // console.log(threads[i]);
    
>! if(mesgs[i] == undefined){
>! console.log("Email Undefined");
>! continue;
>!     }
    var senderAddress = mesgs[i].getFrom();
    var emailSubject = mesgs[i].getSubject();
    
    console.log("Subject: "+emailSubject);
      console.log("Sender Address: "+senderAddress);
      folderPicker_(emailSubject, senderAddress);
      if(threads.length > 0){
    parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName);
  }
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[i].getAttachments();     
      
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var isDefinedType = checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);
        if(!isDefinedType) continue;
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        parentFolder.addFile(file);
        root.removeFile(file);
      }

      threads[i].addLabel(label);
      threads[i].markRead();
      console.log("Sucessfull save to drive and label added");
  }
  
  
  }
```

> Error
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFrom' of undefined
> GmailToDrive    @ Code.gs:40`

Comment: `msgs` is ALL the messages in a given thread. `msgs[i]` is a specific message in a thread, but you are using the sample value of "i"  as you use for the threads loop. For example: "i" might equal 20, but the  thread might contain only two messages, so `msgs[20]` would be undefined. You need to create a second loop to work though the messages.

Comment: When I saw your script, `var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages;` should be `var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();`, and also, it is required to use `mesgs` in another loop. This has already mentioned in the existing comment. But, in your question, you say `It used to work`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. How about this?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Yes it was adding the getMessages() that fixed it. Thanks for the help.